# Why does grid-gap cause an overflow?

Tags: css, css-grid

Why do I have an overflow on the X axis in the following snippet?

The overflow is generated once I apply `grid-gap: 10px` on my `.body` grid container.

```css
div:not(.header):not(.body):not(.row) {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "header-left header-right-up" "header-left header-right-down";
  grid-template-rows: 40px 40px;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(50px, 200px) auto;
}

.header-left {
  grid-area: header-left;
}

.header-right-up {
  grid-area: header-right-up;
}

.header-right-down {
  grid-area: header-right-down;
}

.body {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
  grid-auto-rows: 80px; 
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.row-left {
}

.row-center {
}

.row-right {
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-left">image</div>
  <div class="header-right-up">content</div>
  <div class="header-right-down">long content</div>
</div>

<div class="body">
    <div class="row-left"></div>
    <div class="row-center"></div>
    <div class="row-right"></div>

    <div class="row-left"></div>
    <div class="row-center"></div>
    <div class="row-right"></div>

    <div class="row-left"></div>
    <div class="row-center"></div>
    <div class="row-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdJExz?editors=1100

Comment: Just to note, sometimes you can use margin on the items instead of grid gap.  Hope it helps someone.

Comment: this question is a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489890/grid-column-gap-causes-an-overflow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grid-column-gap causes an overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489890/grid-column-gap-causes-an-overflow)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

### Short Answer

Because the width of the columns plus the width of the gaps is greater than 100%.

---

### Explanation

You have a 3-column grid container (`.body`):

```
grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%
```

The total width of those columns is 100%.

You're then adding gutters between the columns (and rows):

```
grid-gap: 10px
```

which is shorthand for:

```
grid-column-gap: 10px;
grid-row-gap: 10px;
```

So this becomes the width calculation:

```
25% + 50% + 25% + 10px + 10px
```

Hence,

```
100% + 20px > 100%, which results in an overflow condition
```

Note that the `grid-*-gap` properties apply only between grid items – never between items and the container. That's why we calculate two grid gaps, not four.

As a **solution**, instead of percentage units, try using `fr` units, which apply only to free space. This means that `fr` lengths are calculated *after* any `grid-gap` lengths are applied.

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr
```

```css
div:not(.header):not(.body):not(.row) {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "header-left header-right-up" "header-left header-right-down";
  grid-template-rows: 40px 40px;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(50px, 200px) auto;
}

.header-left {
  grid-area: header-left;
}

.header-right-up {
  grid-area: header-right-up;
}

.header-right-down {
  grid-area: header-right-down;
}

.body {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr; /* ADJUSTMENT */
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.row-left {}

.row-center {}

.row-right {}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-left">image</div>
  <div class="header-right-up">content</div>
  <div class="header-right-down">long content</div>
</div>

<div class="body">
  <div class="row-left"></div>
  <div class="row-center"></div>
  <div class="row-right"></div>

  <div class="row-left"></div>
  <div class="row-center"></div>
  <div class="row-right"></div>

  <div class="row-left"></div>
  <div class="row-center"></div>
  <div class="row-right"></div>
</div>
```

[revised codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEGVdK?editors=1100)

More details here: [The difference between percentage and fr units](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090726/3597276)

Comment: another important thing to mention is that using fr units will not always equate to having same size of cells e.g. 50% 50% may not always be half/half. it depends on the content that goes inside cells. To prevent overflow of content or cell to expand to fit content you have to use minmax(0, 1fr) trick. more here: https://css-irl.info/debugging-css-grid-part-2-what-the-fraction/

Comment: FYI - they've just added `gap` and declared `grid-gap` is a 'shorthand' of `gap` in the WD of the spec.

Comment: What if grid-gap causes overflow and I have fr units (never use %)?

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use percentages or some other unit, there is one more solution. The use of the `minmax()` function will allow the columns to shrink to fit the parent container and **not cause overflow**.

The solution would look like this:

```css
grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 25%) minmax(auto, 50%) minmax(auto, 25%);
gap: 10px;
```

More on the `minmax()` function [here](https://learncssgrid.com/#minimum-maximum-grid-track-sizes).

Comment: This fixes overflow but it can result in different width columns, which is likely not desired. As @CodeGems states above, you want to use the minmax(0, 1fr) trick - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214281/why-does-grid-gap-cause-an-overflow/48214864#answer-70154764

Comment: @SamHolguin, OP originally used percentages; ofc. percentages can be presented as fractions, e.g. 1fr, 2fr, 1fr. Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/valgen/z2koh56g/4/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of grid columns that should be the same width and use `grid-gap`, there's a way to do it:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc(25% - 0.75em));
grid-gap: 1em;
```

In this case, each row would have 4 grid columns, and the total space occupied by `grid-gap` would be `3em`. In order to distribute the overflowing space evenly, divide the space by the number of grid columns.

`3em / 4 = 0.75em`

This makes all the grid columns have the same width.

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/tallesaragao/pen/JjGqZVR)

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but 100% worth it.

#### Summary from many resources.

1. Usage with `%`

Grid columns calculated with `%` are not taking into accounts gutters (aka gaps). Therefore you need to add the pixels of the added gaps to the calculation. so `totalGridWidth = SUM(...%) + gutters = ~100% + gutters`

2. Usage with `fr`

The previous issue does not happen **(exception on number 3.)** as it includes to calculate the free space as well with the gaps. so calculation is as follow: `(free space - gutters) / 12  = 1fr` therefore here you could get ratios as fractions instead of portions as percentages.

Or in other words with the Least Common Divisor (1fr = 25%):

`grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;`

3. Usage with `minmax(0,Xfr)`

By default the browser layout engine uses to calculate `Xfr` this formula `minmax(auto,Xfr)` which relies on the minimum size of your items, and when any of those items or inner elements are expected to grow in size indefinitely with things like `width:100%` the `auto` parameter will make still case 2. to run sometimes with overflown grids. To prevent this, we need to force the browser to use a method that can shrink the elements until its real minimum, which is `0px` to do this you need to use `minmax(0,Xfr)` with `X` as the desired fraction.

Or in other words, for your previous case:

`grid-template-columns: minmax(0,1fr) minmax(0,2fr) minmax(0,1fr);`

I know this might look too verbose, but given your such edge case we cannot use `repeat()` here, and in any case, this will be a bulletproof for your overflowing issues.

You can read more in this article I have found:

https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into this problem too, and what it worked for me was to replace  `grid-template-column: 50% 50%;` with `grid-template-column: auto 50%;`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem in using percents:
"  gap: 2%;  "
This becomes to overflow. When I use "px" or other dimension instead of percents (%) - everythisng is ok.